# Why "not a valid LUKS device"?

Tags: debian, encryption, grub, lvm, luks

During installing Debian Squeeze I created partitions on a VPS (`/dev/vda`):

`vda1` = /boot

`vda2` = encrypted LVM (not using a standard way of Debian installer, but with the help of cryptsetup switching to the shell [alt+f2], after that switched back to the installation [alt+f1] and mounted LVs to Debian's directories) with LVs:

```
  - /
  - /var
  - /tmp
  - /home
  - and 3 others
```

Of course I did `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/vda2 vda2_crypted` and `vgchange -s y vg0` before install.

After installing the system says, that it can't find 'debian_root' and it gave up, starting the initramfs shell.

So now I tried `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/vda2 vda2_crypted` but the shell says, that it is not a valid LUKS device.

What could be a problem and a possible solution?